Implementing UART on STM32F030F4P6
I have a custom PCB I recently designed where I used an STM32F030F4P6, and want to use UART communication on the board. The schematic can be found here: https://pdf.ac/CP7hx and I was able to successfully bootload the board and configure my pins.

However, the device on my computer doesn't seem to be recognized as an STM32 device, nor am I sure of how to make it recognized. Currently, the device is just listed as "USB Serial Port (COM4)". I was reading through the Application note (See link here: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf) for system memory boot mode and here is what it said regarding UART:

I then configured the STM32Cube IDE as the following:



I'm just not exactly sure how to upload code via the USB port I have on my PCB and then use the PuTTy terminal when bootloading a board for the first time. I can use my ST-Link with a pogo pin header but I incorporated a UART ic so I would only need the Pogo pin header for the initial bootload and not to upload code every time.

After experimenting for a bit, I was able to get it to work.
So initially I thought post boot loading the board that it would be recognized as the STM32F030F4P6, however it was recognized as FTDI, which is the manufacturer of the UART IC I used. Turns out the video I found on Youtube is only necessary if you want to use Arduino on STM32, which obviously wasn't what I was trying to accomplish.
Post boot loading the board, as mentioned above I flashed the MCU via USB through the STM32CubeProgrammer. I then uploaded my code in the STM32Cube IDE and set my Boot0 pin HIGH, I was able to display text on PuTTy.

The FTDI USB simply implements an USB serial interface. Your PC or the FTDI chip cannot know you have connected an STM32 there, it could be anything.
So in order to communicate with the STM32, the program, whatever it is, must open that specific COM port which you know that is connected to your STM32.
The UART bootloader uses a certain protocol defined by ST.
You cannot upload anything with PuTTy, at least not when MCU is empty.
You must use ST CubeProg or other tools capable of flashing the MCU through the COM port. Simply boot the STM32 into factory programmed system bootloader with the boot pins and connect with CubeProg for flashing the firmware. It can program .bin, .hex, and even .elf files that are output from the build process of CubeIDE.
When you have your own code running, you can use PuTTy or any other terminal to send and receive text.
Of course you can code a custom bootloader that supports any protocol you want and then use PuTTy to upload it. For example ST has an example code with YMODEM receive that could be used to flash the application part to MCU.
The regular PuTTy just may not support serial file transfer protocols so you might need to use some other terminal that does.

Windows Device Manager will just identify the serial port, and give it a COM port number.  I would not expect it to report what, if anything, is connected to that serial port.
Putty or other serial port programs will just report the available COM ports, without reporting what, if anything, is connected to the ports.
I would expect that STM32 programming software would determine if there is an STM32 connected to a COM port (but I haven't used an STM32).

I realized I needed to use the Flash Loader Demonstrater, however, I don't know what file to flash to get the device to be recognized as a STM32F030F4P6, otherwise I can't upload code via USB

@dreece2498 Flash Loader Demonstraror has been replaced years ago with CubeProg. It might not support such new MCUs as F030.
